# function to search in youtube

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I write function for search in youtube.
I create project on "console.developers.google.com" . the name project is youtubesearch and I get apiKey.
I have the error

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'Google.GData.Client.InvalidCredentialsException' occurred in
>   Google.GData.Client.dll"

at foreach loop
my code is:

```
private void getsearch(string serchFor)
        {
            YouTubeRequestSettings setting = new YouTubeRequestSettings("youtubesearch", "APIkey","ise34857@gmail.com","password for my email");
            YouTubeRequest Request = new YouTubeRequest(setting);
            YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(YouTubeQuery.DefaultVideoUri);
            query.OrderBy = "viewCount";
            query.Query = serchFor;
            query.SafeSearch = YouTubeQuery.SafeSearchValues.Moderate;
            Feed<Video> videofeed = Request.Get<Video>(query);
            videoLookUp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (Video v in videofeed.Entries)
            {
                if (v.Media.Content!=null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(v.Title);
                    Console.WriteLine(v.Media.Content.Url);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(v.Title);
                    videoLookUp.Add(v.Title,v.Media.Content.Url);
                }
            }
 }
```

Please check object setting if my parameter is right and tell me if I had any proplem in my code

Comment: You might need to create an app password https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although the YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated, you can check in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Document_Structure) on how to properly authenticate your application using .NET client library. It also shows here how to properly use the `YouTubeRequestSettings` object.

To perform any operation using the YouTube API, you create a `YouTubeRequestSettings` object, which specifies the authentication information and authentication scheme to be used. With that object, you then create a `YouTubeRequest` object that you will use to actually perform the operations. (If you do not specify authentication information when creating the `YouTubeRequestSettings` object, then you will only be able to use the `YouTubeRequest` object to perform operations that do not require authentication.

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = 
new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
```

For more information and sample code, check this [tutorial](https://www.logicum.co/youtube-api-with-asp-net-c/).